# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'facebook'

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to post on facebook page using python. So, I have installed 'facebook'module from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/fb/). But it says
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'facebook'` when I write
**import facebook** in the interpreter. But the install of 'facebook' is successful.

**Installing command in cmd:**

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install fb==0.3.0 Collecting fb==0.3.0   Using
> cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2a/8f/257c73343242229f8b5bc805c938e4618a83879795c4c8cac8637728bfb2/fb-0.3.0.tar.gz
> Installing collected packages: fb   Running setup.py install for fb
> ... done Successfully installed fb-0.3.0

**Is there any wrong on installing process. let me know the process of installation for posting on facebook page using python, please.**

Comment: Better to check how you installed facebook module using pip. The command worked out for me was `$ pip install --user facebook-sdk`

Answer (score 4):

You should use this `pip install facebook-sdk`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `#!/usr/bin/env python3` to find module in any $PATH

Answer (score -2):

[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efyKG.png)

I had the same problem but, **only move the folder that contain the 'facebook' name from the sdk to my project-main-folder**

my principal folder 'facebook-bot-autoresponder-master'(use it as example):
C:\Users\Anibal\Documents\Python Scripts\AutoPostFB\facebook-bot-autoresponder-master